# PHP OAuth API - OAuth client error for Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, api, twitter, oauth

I am using the PHP OAuth API: Authorize and access APIs using OAuth 
by Manuel Lemos

[PHP OAuth API](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html)

This class can authorize the access of users to an API using the OAuth protocol.

It abstracts OAuth 1.0, 1.0a and 2.0 in the same class, so you can use the same obtain a token to authorize the access on behalf of the current user any API that supports any version of the OAuth protocol.

The issue i am facing is, while authenticating my facebook account I get a strange error after i am redirected from facebook to this page
Script: oauth-api/login_with_facebook.php

Error:

> OAuth client error
>
> Error: it was not specified the body value of the of the API call
>   request

Example: [PHP OAUTH login_with_facebook.php](http://www.nockbits.com/apps/phpoauth/oauth-api/login_with_facebook.php)

Any suggestions?

Comment: This problem was fixed in the latest version. Please update. Thank you for reporting anyway.